# Copy SharePoint Designer Workflow to another Farm

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have created a infopath form and attached a custom approval workflow and infopath form is published to a forms library. I have done everything in my development VM. I have also published the infopath form to my Test environment. How Do I copy the SPD Workflow from my Development environment to the Test Environment and attach to the infopath form.

There should be a MS Recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends,

For MOSS 2007, there is no supported way of doing this.  Basicly you need to copy the .XOML file attach it to new work flow and then replace all the GUIDS.  There are plenty of posts you will get via google on it.  There is a utility on codeplex to automate this, but use at your own risk:

http://spdtoolkit.codeplex.com/site/search?query=SPDToolkit&ac=3

For 2010, you export your workflow as a .WSP and import it into the production farm.  It will import as a farm solution however.  You can also edit the .WSP in Visual Studio at this point (but you can't use SPD after).  If the InfoPath forms is part of the workflow (data collection form) it will be packaged with .WSP export.  If it is just a seperate form You will want to publish your InfoPath form directly to the production farm.  You could technically build (or incorporate it into) a WSP to deploy your infopath form as well.